How do I transpose row values in Data Frame to new columns based on shared column ID?
I have a dataframe containing item IDs with several different attributes.
Item IDs are listed in rows, with each attribute in adjoining cells beside them. Please take a look at the table below for illustration.

How do I write a python pandas  script to automatically detect rows of similar Item IDs and move (cut and paste) their attributes into a new column beside them? The result I have in mind is identical to the table below.

I am certain that some sort of pivot table script that uses pandas or openpyxl will be appropriate, but none of the solutions I have come across (both here and elsewhere) are germane to my specific case. Any help will be appreciated.

Please, take some time to read how to ask and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Never post code as images.

Thanks for you comment but I am not sure what you mean posting code as image. i did not post any code.

That's the problem. No code to work with. Both links in my previous comment still apply and btw, input data counts as code in this case.

Hi strunge, welcome to Stack Overflow! In addition to what LMC said, I would say, do the attribute numbers have any meaning (e.g. are the colors in order?)

Thanks for your comment. It is not exactly clear to me what you mean bouy them "having any meaning'. In this case, the attributes are sort of like, the observed characteristics of items. Thus different colors indicates that a specific item has different color properties. If items have different properties they appear one after another with each color property beside. Just like shown in the image

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You need to pivot your data from long format to wide format. Check out pd.pivot() Your index will be your IDs and your values will be your colors.
In order to generate column names ('Attribute 1', 'Attribute 2', etc) you will need to take your data apart, create the structure you need, then add the colors info back in.

Grab just your Items column and remove duplicates. Create a list of your 5 Attribute_Options (or the max number of colors you need in one row eventually). Then join these together using a cross join. You will have one row for each combination of Item and Attribute_Option.

Join your original colors information to the structure you set up. Use a left join and use the Items as your key.

Then do your pivot passing Attribute_Options to columns.



Thanks for your answer. I am aware of the pivot operation. If you look closely at the results table illustrated in my question, you will notice that new column names are created to house the pivot values. My problem is, how do I make pandas automatically create new columns to house the attributes in the pivoted table, as seen in the image illustration for the results table? This is what I am struggling with currently

To clarify what I meant above, I am looking to create the pivot so new column names are made that aren't derived from an existing column

I see.. I will edit my answer with something you can try.

Thank you very much for elaborating on your earlier comment. I am still stuck trying to get your instructions to work on my data. In reality, the data I have is more complex than I posted earlier. First of all, about 5000+ rows require transposing. Also, there is no particular pattern to the rows to use for the transposing except that the data to be transposed all share similar ID numbers.

Please see this link for an illustration and a description of the data: https://imgur.com/7jwtu2T. Here is also a copy of the data I am working on. It is only a subset  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p2EmFeKaboHaDgTvVS4BI6JmbEH2T2ya/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106376732125126588854&rtpof=true&sd=true
